# Enable UserInteraction to some part of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have been researching about it since last 3 to 4 hours but I didn't get any information. My issue is I want to enable userInteraction to some part of the UIViewController.

**Description:**

I have a UIViewController. I have added 30 tableviews. I have stored one value in the application. If that value is 1 then I have to enable user interaction for tableview1 only and if the value is 2 then tableview2 only ........etc

. Please let me know if I am not clear. Thank you for spending your valuable time. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just loop over your 30 tableViews, set tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO for all but the one with the good value ?

Comment: Sorry I  need help in implementing the loop

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is to subclass UIView and override `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.

Return NO for the part of the UIView (represented as `ignoreRect` in the sample) you want the subviews to ignore touches.

```
@interface InteractionView ()

@property (nonatomic) CGRect ignoreRect;

@end

@implementation InteractionView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.ignoreRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f);
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.ignoreRect, point)) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

If you need more tweaking for an expected behavior : for exemple return a specific view for a specific zone, return the top view of a specific zone, ... you may use

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.ignoreRect, point)) {
        return nil; // Edit that part if you want to return a chosen view
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Tanguy G thank you. I will try it and make it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event.` is to adding `UIButton` as a subview to the part of `UIView` you want to close interaction. 
for example if you want to close interaction of the bottom half of view.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height*0.5f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height*0.5);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

since it will get the touch events, half of the view will be closed to user interaction.

**EDIT**

```
IBOutletCollection(UITableView) NSArray *allTableViews;// get all your tableviews reference to this array. set tag in interface builder for each array to reach later.
```

then when you want to enable/disable interaction of related `tableview`

```
int tagToOpenInteraction = 1;//or whatever it is
for(UITableView *t in allTableViews)
{
     if(t.tag == tagToOpenInteraction)
         [t setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     else
        [t setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];  
}
```